# glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW) use giving segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am trying to implement a camera for an fps like project and I am having trouble when using my Camera class on the main.cpp when calling the `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)`.

Here are the relevant functions:

```
void Camera::init() {

    m_yaw = 0.0;
    m_pitch = 0.0;
    set_pos(0,0,0);
}

void Camera::set_pos(float x, float y, float z) {
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
    m_z = z;

    refresh();
}

void Camera::refresh() {
    m_lx = cos(m_yaw) * cos(m_pitch);
    m_ly = sin(m_pitch);
    m_lz = sin(m_yaw) * cos(m_pitch);

    m_strafe_lx = cos(m_yaw - M_PI_2);
    m_strafe_lz = sin(m_yaw - M_PI_2);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    printf("the segmentation fault is above!\n");
    gluLookAt(m_x, m_y, m_z, m_x + m_lx, m_y + m_ly, m_z + m_lz, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    //printf("Camera: %f %f %f Direction vector: %f %f %f\n", m_x, m_y, m_z, m_lx, m_ly, m_lz);
}
```

Comment: Do you have an OpenGL context when you run this? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: Even without a GL context this shouldn't segfault. Most likely there's an out-of-bounds write somewhere else in the program corrupting runtime housekeeping structures and the call of glLoadIdentity triggers the collapse. This is where one gets a memory debugger like Valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

In case if you include glew.h, you need to initialize beforehand, otherwise GL API calls are replaced with null function pointers and causes segfaults.